# How to check if an item was instantiated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have four buttons with a certain amount of items, and I would like to spawn them once I have clicked on them on my mouse position and decrease the amount afterward. What should I do to check if an object was instantiated so that the items can be reduced?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing the structure of your code. But I would say that whatever script is instantiating the object should notify whatever needs to know to decrease the items.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.